# $A= x^3 + y^3 +z^3 + kxyz $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Let $x,y,z$ are three sides of a triangle such that $x+y+z=3$. Find $k \geq 0$ such that:
$$A= x^3 + y^3 +z^3 + kxyz $$ have minimum.

I tried for this: $k=6,k=15,k=\frac{15}{4}$ and it have all minimum, which is easy with Schur.

Comment: Check this post for some hints: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039184/extreme-values-of-x3-y3-z3-3xyz-subject-to-ax-by-cz-1-usin

Comment: I think it isn't help

Comment: To @Lục Trường Phát: are you familiar with Lagrange multiplier method?

Comment: Im just at grade 10:) I sometime here it in solving the number series @AntonVrdoljak